# Using GetWindowTextW to get Hebrew text from edit control

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, internationalization

I have a VisualStudio project set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set.  It's an older codebase and generally I've been able to get around ok using the "W" version of various functions.  However I'm running into a problem trying to get a Hebrew string out of an edit control.  No matter what I try I get question marks.

E.g.

```
int textLen = GetWindowTextLengthW(chatBoxHwnd);
wchar_t* buffw = new wchar_t[textLen + 1];  
GetWindowTextW(chatBoxHwnd, buffw, textLen + 1);
```

But when I try to use buffw (such as displaying it with MessageBoxW) I still get question marks.

Comment: What characters are present if you look at it in the debugger? (That is, look at buf after the call to GetWindowTextW).

Comment: Note that per the docs, "GetWindowTextLength cannot retrieve the length of the text of an edit control in another application" and GetWindowText "cannot retrieve the text of an edit control in another application". What do these functions return?

Comment: The question marks mean the text is going through a charset conversion using a charset that does not support the characters being converted. When "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" is used, HWNDs are ANSI, not UNICODE, so try using the ANSI APIs (`GetWindowTextLengthA()`, `GetWindowTextA()`) instead of the Unicode APIs. See `IsWindowUnicode()`. Except that you can't use the `GetWindowText...()` functions across process boundaries, so use `SendMessageA()` with `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and `WM_GETTEXT` instead, and then convert to Unicode afterwards using a Hebrew codepage.

Comment: It's all in the same application. I don't think there should be any issues with process boundaries?  As long as I'm typing in ANSI characters it works fine. I'll try using the A versions and converting with the appropriate code page.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Show a [mcve] ...

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to also use the Unicode version for creating the edit control itself ( CreateWindowExW vs CreateWindowEX) as well as the ancillary functions around that (SendMessageW, SetWindowLongPtrW, etc...)
After that I was able to successfully use the above code to pull Hebrew (and other languages) from the edit box.

Special thanks to this post [How to create a unicode window in a non-unicode application](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2009/12/22/how-to-create-a-unicode-window-in-a-non-unicode-application/)